# How can I pass a returned VARCHAR from a SELECT statement in a stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Relevant code:

```
SELECT `startdate`, `problem` 
INTO tktCompletedDate, problem
FROM servicerequest 
WHERE (requestID = tktRequestID);
    
CASE problem
    WHEN "Screen is broken" THEN 
        SET tktProbSpec = 'installed replacement screen';
    ELSE SET tktProbSpec = 'Ran Diagnostics';
END CASE;
```

Trying to complete a class assignment (big surprise) and when I run this SELECT is returns the `startdate` and passes it into tktCompletedDate variable no problem, but the `problem` field does not get passed. When I check it later it says the value is NULL.

Comment: I suggest changing the variable name `problem` so it is not the same as the column `problem` in that table. I am not certain this is the cause of your issue, but it would be good to maintain a habit of making variable names distinct from column names in the same query. This causes a lot of confusion if only for readability when the variable names and column names are spelled the same.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: is problem in servicerequest is null?